# configure apache run run php in html pages

Tags: apache

How can I make apache parse php code inside my html pages? I don't wanna use .htaccess. I've added:

```
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html 
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

in my vhost file for one of the websites but it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem in the latest versions (Debian 10 , Apache 2.4.25, PHP 7.0.33)
My solution is edit the php.config file, to find it I put:

```
find -iname php*.conf
```

...and in my debian instalation I found it in:

```
 /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf
```

Then, I introduce those lines at begining:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you build your Apache binary with PHP? Or if you built a SO, reference it in the Apache config (e.g.: LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so)?

When using .html for PHP, ensure 'AddType text/html .html' is removed, so it doesn't conflict with the x-httpd-php reference.

FYI -- you can create one entry 'AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php'

Comment: Hi Jerry. Thank's for answering. Well ... apache and php are already working together. The code in *.php pages is being parsed. So, the php pages are working. Anyway, I've finally manage to get it working ... there was a "AddType text/html .html" declaration somewhere in the hosts configs which I stuppidly missed. After removing that it now works. The html pages which contain php code are getting processed.

Comment: That would explain it. It was conflicting with the that line. I will update my answer for others. Good find!